# MySQL high lock_time on UPDATE query leads to server freeze

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

This is killing me. Please help me. My production server freeze once a week. There were queries that lock rows, and block other queries, consuming 100% CPU all the time. I need to manually kill those frozen queries before the server coming back working.

I have a system that will show the highest CTR banners on the website based on any given slot. This is my table structure.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `banners` (
  `banner_id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `banner_slot` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `banner_img_path` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `banner_link` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `banner_views` int(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `banner_clicks` int(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `banner_ctr` double(5,3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`banner_id`),
  KEY `banner_slot` (`banner_slot`,`banner_views`,`banner_ctr`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=4231;
```

This runs on production server (CentOS6.3/MySQL 5.5.28/Apache2/Quad core CPU/8GB RAM). Pretty old, I know.

The server also runs a few more wordpress sites, which I already use the WP super cache plugin. There are some queries from wordpress appears in slow query log file, but they are all under 5 seconds.

Recently, I've got approx 20K page views daily. With about 2-3K UIPs at peak hours (all domains combined).

This is my my.cnf settings:

```
innodb_file_per_table=1
open_files_limit=10192
skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size=800M
max_allowed_packet=100M
table_open_cache=512
table_cache=500
sort_buffer_size=2M
read_buffer_size=4M
read_rnd_buffer_size=8M
thread_cache_size=4
query_cache_type=0
query_cache_size=4M
join_buffer_size=8M
tmp_table_size=512M
max_heap_table_size=256M
max_connections=200
```

This is my slow query log file. You'll see that there is high lock time on such a basic query here.

```
# Query_time: 84.554967  Lock_time: 37.070954 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
use db_name;
SET timestamp=1537010708;
UPDATE banners SET banner_views=banner_views+1 WHERE banner_id=6;
# Query_time: 84.614748  Lock_time: 37.130587 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
use db_name;
SET timestamp=1537010708;
UPDATE banners SET banner_views=banner_views+1 WHERE banner_id=60;
# Query_time: 54.288041  Lock_time: 0.000018 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
SET timestamp=1537010708;
UPDATE banners SET banner_views=banner_views+1 WHERE banner_id=884;
# Query_time: 104.154232  Lock_time: 34.661097 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
use db_name;
SET timestamp=1537010744;
UPDATE banners SET banner_views=banner_views+1 WHERE banner_id=60;
# Query_time: 107.847145  Lock_time: 38.354068 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
SET timestamp=1537010744;
UPDATE banners SET banner_views=banner_views+1 WHERE banner_id=6;
# Query_time: 81.974780  Lock_time: 26.446288 Rows_sent: 0 Rows_examined: 1
SET timestamp=1537010771;
UPDATE banners SET banner_views=banner_views+1 WHERE banner_id=6;
# Query_time: 102.331612  Lock_time: 46.507686 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
use db_name;
SET timestamp=1537010772;
UPDATE banners SET banner_views=banner_views+1 WHERE banner_id=60;
# Query_time: 81.808158  Lock_time: 36.196089 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
SET timestamp=1537010772;
UPDATE banners SET banner_views=banner_views+1 WHERE banner_id=7;
```

I've gone through mysql-tuner.pl and almost all settings are green based on the recommendations.

I'm also EXPLAINING all the SELECT queries, and those are all using indexes. I couldn't EXPLAIN on any other queries since I'm running on MySQL 5.5.

Any recommendations on my issue? Thanks in advance! Any help are appreciated!

Comment: "I'm also EXPLAINING all the SELECT queries, and those are all using indexes. I couldn't EXPLAIN on any other queries since I'm running on MySQL 5.5. " You can rewrite a UPDATE query into a SELECT query.. `UPDATE banners SET banner_views=banner_views+1 WHERE banner_id=6;` is more or less the same as `SELECT banner_views+1 WHERE banner_id=6;` then you can use a `EXPLAIN`... Also the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE banners` would be nice.

Comment: Can you check your `innodb_buffer_pool_size` ? Also check this answer https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27341/160363

Comment: what happens if you make query `banner_views=banner_views` . I mean when you don't increase banner_views ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya my innodb_buffer_pool_size is  
134217728. Based on your link, I got a '1' as the answer. Is this way too high?

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thanks. EXPLAIN SELECT banner_views+1 FROM banners WHERE banner_id=6; shows that I'm using the primary key, length 4.

Comment: @jessica you can set your innodb_buffer_pool_size to 1G

Comment: @Jessica you may want to consider the possibility that these slow queries are not the actual problem, but a symptom.  Cloud servers are cheap, and it might make sense to move this traffic elsewhere, to isolate it.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot actually I'm on a dedicate server.

Comment: @jessica  Have you considered running  OPTIMIZE TABLE banners;  ?  Likely will eliminate table page fragmentation due to transactions posted in past few weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Rate Per Second= RPS

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
# 20180916 12:30  by  mysqlservertuning.com

query_cache_size=0  # from 4M conserve RAM & CPU QC type=0 = OFF to start with
read_buffer_size=128K  # from 4M to reduce CPU busy & handler_read_next RPS
read_rnd_buffer_size=256K  # from 8M to reduce CPU busy & handler_read_rnd_next RPS
join_buffer_size=128K  # from 8M to conserve RAM
thread_cache_size=32  # from 4 to reduce threads_created & CPU overhead
max_heap_table_size=512M  # from 256M should be same as tmp_table_size always
```

Copy existing my.cnf for back up somewhere, (just in case) then

Date line and all 6 variables to be copied to END of [mysqld] section of my.cnf 
to override previous requested values.

STOP/START your instance or RESTART your instance.  Please SKYPE me, when time permits.